# Accessing Type Metatables Lua

Tags: lua

Its obviously that getmetatable can access the metatables of several types:

```
getmetatable("")
getmetatable({})
getmetatable(newproxy(true))
```

However it appears as though you cannot get the metatable of other types (functions aside).  There appears to be no way to access the metatable of numbers, booleans, or nil.

I was also wondering if one would be able to access a metatable of the entire table type.  To be able to do something like this:

```
({}) + ({})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers, Booleans and nil have no metatable by default (hence getmetatable returning `nil`). You can give them one with `debug.setmetatable` though.

There is no common table metatable. (and same for userdata (at least of the heavy variety))

Comment: Thanks.  Just wanted to know that.

Answer (score 5):

strings, numbers, nil, functions and lightuserdata have a single metatable for the whole type.  tables and full userdata have a metatable for each instance.

from the docs:

> Tables and full userdata have
>   individual metatables (although
>   multiple tables and userdata can share
>   their metatables). Values of all other
>   types share one single metatable per
>   type; that is, there is one single
>   metatable for all numbers, one for all
>   strings, etc.strings, etc.

there's no 'table type metatable', just like there's no 'metatable for this string'

the string type has the 'string' table as metatable by default; but you can set the metatable for other types using the `debug.setmetatable()` function.strings, etc.