# Cycling through different file location options

Tags: lua, lookup, file-location

I'm essentially trying to create a function which tests the first location I give, in the form:

```
 myComputer.referenceLookup("/address/x/text")
```

and return the string in that location if it is not NULL or "None" or "" (empty).

If not, I want it to test the next possible location:

```
 myComputer.referenceLookup("/address/1/x/text")
```

Otherwise, I would like it to return an empty string ("").

I've tried looking in the [Lua Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3) to no avail as well as testing different forms in repl.it, but unfortunately, I can't replicate a similar example as I usually do when testing.

```
function firstLine(x)

if myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/ .. (x) .. /text") != NULL or "None" or "" then

    return myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/ .. (x) .. /text")

elseif myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/1/ .. (x) .. /text") !=  NULL or "None" or "" then

    return myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/1/ .. (x) .. /text")

else

    return ""

end

end

myComputer.out.firstHouseNumber = firstLine(housenumber)
```

It's worth noting that the usual way I would reference the fact is as follows:

```
myComputer.out.firstHouseNumber= myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/housenumber/text")
```

or

```
myComputer.out.firstHouseNumber= myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/1/housenumber/text")
```

The platform I'm using doesn't throw errors, it just will return blank instead of running the lua script so I am unable to debug (hence usually using repl.it).

I know this makes it a bit of an abstract question, but if anyone knows how I can do what I am describing, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: when you say `return the string in that location` do you mean you are looking to read the text file and return the contents?  or just return the validated path? -- Side note on your question: the lua example of firstLine is not valid lua. uses `NULL` rather than `nil`, `!=` rather than `~=`, and `"/Address/ .. (x) .. /text"` would not have the desired effect(it's missing some additional `"`)

Comment: @Nifim, Ideally, return the string which is at that location, my mistake about the != and the ~=, I've been converting from the DSL which the system used to Lua and confusingly, the ~= is used as approx. equal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assumptions

Looking at your answer, I will assume that

1. `myComputer.referenceLookup` is defined somewhere else and works as intended (and not part of this question)
2. `NULL` is also defined somewhere else and represents some sort of nil-value

### Answer

The line

```
if myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/ .. (x) .. /text") != NULL or "None" or "" then
```

doesn't work, because the `or` operator doesn't work that way.

How Lua interprets it is

```
if (myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/ .. (x) .. /text") != NULL) or "None" or ""
```

and since "None" is a String value and thus considered truthy, the if condition will always evaluate to true, so it will always return the first location. Also, there is no `!=` operator in Lua; it's `~=` instead.

As for a solution, you essentially need three comparisons like this:

```
if myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/" .. x .. "/text") ~= NULL
and myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/" .. x .. "/text") ~= "None"
and myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/" .. x .. "/text") ~= "" then
```

Obviously calling the function three times is a bad idea, both because of performance and because it may have side effects, so it's better to save it into a variable first like so:

```
local result = myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/" .. (x) .. "/text")
if result ~= NULL and result  ~= "None" and result  ~= "" then
  return result
end
```

### Extra

If you want to make your program easier to extend, you can also use [`string.format`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format) to build the locations from templates. Say you have a table containing all your locations like this:

```
local locations = {
  "/Address/%s/text";
  "/Address/1/%s/text";
}
```

Then you can iterate through the entries using [`ipairs`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs) and build each location using `string.format`:

```
for index, template in ipairs(locations) do
  local result = myComputer.referenceLookup(template:format(x))
  if result ~= NULL and result  ~= "None" and result  ~= "" then
    return result
  end
end
```

Note that you can write `string.format(template, x)` as `template:format(x)` as long as template is a string. ([further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052241/lua-when-is-it-possible-to-use-colon-syntax))

Comment: Thanks very much for that! My mistake about the != and the ~=, I've been converting from the DSL which the system used to Lua and confusingly, the ~= is used as approx. equal! The Extra help is also greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, one more question! The location of the file is: myComputer.referenceLookup("/Address/example/text") not myComputer.referenceLookup(/Address/example/text). I.e. the quotation marks around the location. I'm wondering how that is going to work in this situation

Comment: @Bee I don't really get what you mean by that, sorry. The example without the quotation marks would not be valid Lua syntax at all.

Comment: That's basically what I'm saying, if you concat the bit inside the brackets as you have above, would it still return a string and therefore a valid address? I assume from your response that that is a yes, I'm fairly new to Lua so just trying to get my head around it!

Comment: @Bee short answer: `"hello" .. "world"` is the exact same as `"helloworld"`, there's absolutely no difference. Long answer: [Official Reference, 3.4.6 – Concatenation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.6)

Comment: Ok thanks, I was just wondering if it would work the same in a lookup, but I suppose it makes sense that it would. Thanks again!